# deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: no kind "deployment" is registered for version

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, kubectl, minikube

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLebels:
       app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      lebels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
     containers:
     - name: mongodb
       image: mongo
       ports:
       - containerPort: 27017
       env:
       - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAE
         valueFrom:
           secretKeyref:
             name: mongodb-secret
             key: mongo-root-username
       - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
         valueFrom:
          secretKeyref:
            name: mongodb-secret
            key: mongo-root-password
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WWqj.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There are multiple typos in the yaml you have provided in the question.
- I have corrected them as following , use following yaml and check

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment    #corrected typo deployment to Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:            #corrected typo matchLebels to matchLabels
       app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:               #corrected typo lebels to labels
        app: mongodb
    spec:
     containers:
     - name: mongodb
       image: mongo
       ports:
       - containerPort: 27017
       env:
       - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAE
         valueFrom:
           secretKeyRef:                  #corrected typo secretKeyref to secretKeyRef
             name: mongodb-secret
             key: mongo-root-username
       - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
         valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:                  #corrected typo secretKeyref to secretKeyRef
            name: mongodb-secret
            key: mongo-root-password
```

Answer (score 1):

kind Deployment is case sensitive, use capital D

```
kind: Deployment
```

Comment: What error you are getting now? paste your yml file also.

Answer (score 0):

If above suggestion did not work..then check your kubernetes version. Probably you are using old version which does not support apps/v1 api.

Answer (score 0):

You can please check the `deployment` version **Kubernetes** supporting.

Try this command :

```
kubectl api-resources
```

according to that change the version in YAML file instead of `apps/v1` maybe it will be `apps/v1beta2`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: deployment
```

command

```
kubectl api-resources
```

will print the all supported API version by the cluster you are running.